# Unity3D: Aspect ratio issue

Tags: unity-game-engine

In Unity3D I can't scale the game properly to remove the black bar.

I've added pictures for reference:

[image]

EDIT: I need to make the canvas scale to the whole screen instead of only a part of the screen.

Comment: We need to know a bit more background information before we can help you. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for details. If your problem is not code related, then it is considered to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow - however, you might be able to get useful information over at http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why Does My Unity Game Not Display At Full Size On Some Devices?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42624101/why-does-my-unity-game-not-display-at-full-size-on-some-devices)

Comment: I have [already provided an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42624101/why-does-my-unity-game-not-display-at-full-size-on-some-devices/42630451#42630451) to the same exact issue.

Answer (score 4):

You should first set your game viewport to simulate the resolution and screen size of whatever you're building for. Change **Free Aspect** to the appropriate aspect ratio or manually add a new resolution.

Also, I believe the match mode you want for your Canvas Scaler is **Match Width or Height**.

Answer (score 3):

You have to set anchors of Image to each corner of your canvas display so It can scale accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the aspect ratio from 'free aspect' to '16:9' or manually enter an aspect ratio that suits your needs.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try to dynamically spawn the background or image by using Scale To Fit lots of Unity Documentation to help with that so when compiled you can tend to get a stronger and fuller picture this may help with a general sizing issue

Answer (score 0):

Set the screen resolution manually in the `Start()` of your code:

```
Screen.SetResolution(x, y, true)
```